# Is it a smart idea to use setInterval to update a time frequently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, momentjs

How much of an impact on the server would there be if I used a setInterval like this to continue changing the time displayed in the browser every 10 seconds for example:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var time = moment($('#bidTime').val());
  $('#ago').text(time.fromNow());
  $('#ago2').text(time.fromNow());
}, 10000);
```

On the dashboard of my web app, I have a "Last Updated" column with a displayed time that I want to display "xx seconds ago" etc..

Is it bad to use setInterval in this case? Is there a better way?

Comment: Where is a request made to server at `javascript`?

Comment: No impact on the server at all.... Javascript is run in the clients browser. Javascript is a client-side language.

Comment: No server imapct this is clientside.

Comment: Client side code like that is fine.  What can be bad (and get an IP address blacklisted) is if you have script code that makes an AJAX request to the server every second.  Don't ever do that without a very good reason.

Comment: This code doesn't make any ajax calls, or set any hrefs or make any other changes that would cause the browser to communicate with the server, so why would it be expected to have any impact on the server?

Comment: You're doing it the right way. Remember to call clearInterval() on the value returned by setInterval() if you stop showing the time without navigating to a different page. (Common case for single-page web apps.)